# Regex for first 20 words of markdown

Tags: regex, markdown

I need to read the first twenty words of a blog post written in markdown, so I can display them as a preview text on the overview page. The markdown could look like this:

```
# A new horizon
#### Subtitle
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam   voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

#### Second title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam   voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita   kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

There are a few rules:

- Don't use headlines starting with #
- Select the 20 first words including punctuation, numbers or special chars like ä, ö, ü
- Select less than 20 words if there are not enough in the post
- If word selecting is impossible, select the 100 first chars matching the above rules

I'm using JavaScript on the server to do this, so any other/ a mixed approach is appreciated.

Regexr with my not so much working approach: http://regexr.com/3fk2f

Comment: One single regex probably won't suit your needs, especially with JS engine which is quite poor (e.g. missing lookbehinds which could be quite useful here). Better implement your own algorithm, e.g. remove lines starting with `#`, split by space, etc.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/ODk4Uc/1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could do the job:

```
^(?!#) *((?:\S+(?: |$)+){1,20})
```

See it [live](https://regex101.com/r/ODk4Uc/1)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, a mixed approach with a simpler regex and Javascript:

```
var md = post.markdown.replace(/#+.+\n/gm, '').split(' ').slice(0, 20).join(' ');
```

`/#+.+\n/gm` matches every line starting with # until the line break, we remove all those lines.

Then we split the remaining string at the white spaces which gives us an array of words (commas, special chars etc. are attached to the words).

We slice this array to get the 20 first entries and join them back together with a whitespace.